# Telnet to Gmail SMTP "starttls auth" syntax error

Tags: smtp, telnet

When I Telnet gmail and send an email using cmd promt, everything works fine. After `Telnet smtp.gmail.com 587`, following conversation with the server happens:

```
220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP m184sm839913wme.40 - gsmtp

helo google

250 smtp.gmail.com at your service

**starttls auth**

555 5.5.2 **Syntax error**. m184sm839913wme.40 - gsmtp

auth login

334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
```

Rest I have deleted.

Despite the syntax error highlighted above it works fine. What is the error about? And how does it still work? If i do not write the **STARTTLS AUTH**, it does not work. I do not know much about TLS apart from the fact it is related to security

Comment: Could you try to use "ehlo" instead of "helo" ?

Comment: Do you actually plan to use Telnet or are you just testing to see if the port is open and accepts commands?

Comment: I am just learning networks as a beginner. :)

Comment: @S.Brottes 
EHLO google

250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [39.32.198.204]

250-SIZE 35882577

250-8BITMIME
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-PIPELINING
250-CHUNKING
250 SMTPUTF8
starttls auth
555 5.5.2 Syntax error. l8sm1083550wme.18 - gsmtp